# Write An azure function with Javascript that is connecting OracleDB and running on Docker

Tags: node.js, oracle, docker, npm, azure-functions

- I have an Azure Function that is written with Visual Studio Code and it is a nodejs application with javascript codes.
- Also, the application connects to Oracle DB to run an Oracle Script.
- Also, the application runs on a Docker image.

I added the npm packages for oracle connection;

```
npm i express
npm i oracledb
```

Below my some key points of code;

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:3.0
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true
COPY . /home/site/wwwroot
RUN cd /home/site/wwwroot && \
npm install
```

**index.js**

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
let responseMessage = "";
let connection;
try {
    const oracledb = require('oracledb');
    connection = await oracledb.getConnection({
        user: "xx",
        password: "xx",
        connectString: req.body
    });

    let query = 'select * from xx where rownum=1';
    result = await connection.execute(query);
    responseMessage = result;
} catch (err) {
    responseMessage = err.message;
} finally {
    if (connection) {
      try {
        // Always close connections
        await connection.close(); 
      } catch (err) {
        responseMessage = err.message;
      }
    }
  }
context.res = {
    body: responseMessage
};
}
```

Here is my folder structure of project;

[image]

**CASE1**: When I run the project with "func start" the application is working properly and gets the result.

**CASE2**: When I run it on my local docker with below steps it returns an error form HTTP response.

1. Run "docker build ."
2. docker run -d -p 99:80 myimage
3. It is listed on "docker ps" list.
4. I call the endpoint "http://localhost:99/api/HttpExample" I get an error.

> DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html for help
> Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html
> You must have 64-bit Oracle client libraries in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or configured with ldconfig.
> If you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from
> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html

I search some documentations but I can't find the solution for especially Azure Function Project. Because my dockerfile have to be created based on "FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:3.0".

What should be the Dockerfile for this project?

Comment: Can you not copy Instant Client in your Dockerfile?  See some of the example ways to do this in https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python-part-1 One of these might work for you.